# RDBMS for Big Data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

We have scenario where the csv (>900 GB) data files are stored in the HDFS files system , over which a Hive 0.14 Table is been defined. We need to perform few analytical queries on the data as well as perform updates on the data. Basically a RDBMS kind of system on this volume of data. Can any one suggest what are potential options for RDBMS kind of system (Updates, Select ) keeping in the mind performance being a important criteria.

Comment: Hive supports update and analytical queries. Anything specific u want to achieve which you are not able to do using Hive?

Comment: @piyushpankaj hive does support updates but it'll be very costly if you consider this much data.

Comment: Thats the exact problem we are facing. We want to try and keep the updates as quick as possible , as there could be multiple system which might derived certain metrics that needs to updated to the data in the Hive Table

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is a great option to load data from an EDL. You can put your hot data there to execute some fast querys.

Comment: This looks to a little difficult as we are trying to load the batch data on the daily basis. Now the volume of batch data on daily basis could be nearly around 300GB + . Putting this data into postgres would itself be time consuming job. We are looking for some kind of RDBMS on big data world which are available as open source